# Manage http access to git repositories using gitosis

Tags: http, git

**[Update 9/16/2010]**

After looking into this last night, I realized that my original question was really asking 2 separate things:

1) Is it possible to set the post-update hook for all remote repositories created by gitosis (i.e. not have to manually perform `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` for after creating a repository in gitosis).  This is necessary for cloning via HTTP to work (dumb HTTP clients rely on the fact that `git update-server-info` is called from within the post-update hook).

2) Once the repository is accessible via HTTP, is it possible to turn access on and off using an option in gitosis.conf (something similar to `daemon = no` or `gitweb = yes`)

**--- Solution to question 1 ---**

It turns out that Git uses templates to create new repositories with the `git init` command.  By performing `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` within the template directory, all future calls to `git init` on my server will have the post-update hook configured correctly.  (On OSX the template directory is `/opt/local/share/git-core/templates/` for those that care)

The other requirement for this to work is turning on Apache rewrite rules so that the HTTP clone URL for the repository looks like `http//git.example.com/repo.git`

My rewrite rules in `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` look like this:

```
# turning on mod rewrite
RewriteEngine on

# make the front page an internal rewrite to the gitweb script
RewriteRule ^/$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi [L,PT]

# make access for "dumb clients" work
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.git/(?!/?(HEAD|info|objects|refs)).*)?$ /cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi%{REQUEST_URI} [L,PT]
```

**--- Still looking for a solution to question 2...HELP! :) ---**

Now that HTTP cloning works for all my repositories, I'm wondering if there is a way to manage HTTP access control using gitosis.  Setting `daemon = no` and `gitweb = no` turns off git-daemon and gitweb access for the repository, but since the Apache rewrite rules are still on, ***the repo is still clone-able*** at `http://git.example.com/repo.git`.  Any ideas on how to use gitosis to manage this?

**[The question I originally posted]**

Is it possible to manage http access to git repositories using gitosis?  For example, in gitosis.conf I can manage access for gitweb and git-demon using:

```
# Allow gitweb to show this repository.
gitweb = yes

# Allow git-daemon to publish this repository.
daemon = no
```

I'm currently able to clone my repository by issuing the following command:

```
$ git clone git://git.example.com/repo.git
```

However, when I issue the following command:

```
$ git clone http://git.example.com/repo.git
```

I get the following error message:

```
fatal: http://git.example.com/repo.git/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

However, if I log into my server and run the following from within repo.git:

```
# From http://progit.org/book/ch4-5.html
$ cd project.git
$ mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
$ chmod a+x hooks/post-update
$ git update-server-info
```

then cloning via http works fine.

Is there any way to manage http access to the repository from within gitosis?

Comment: Please provide more informations: apache.conf/your git config part in apache, your gitweb.conf...

Answer (score 1):

Gitosis uses gitweb for http publishing of repositories.

You need to have gitweb running.

Please ensure that gitweb is installed. Your gitweb.conf should look like:

```
# Location of the git binary
$GIT = "/usr/bin/git";

# Project root for gitweb
$projectroot = "/srv/git/repositories";

$stylesheet = "/gitweb.css";
$logo = "/git-logo.png";
$favicon = "/git-favicon.png";

# Site name
$site_name = "My site";

# URL formatting
#$my_uri = "http://git.somewhere.net/";
#$home_link = $my_uri;

# Base URL for project trees
@git_base_url_list = ("ssh://git\@somewhere.net");

# Length of the project description column in the webpage.
$projects_list_description_width = 50;

# Which repos are allowed to export
$export_ok = "git-daemon-export-ok";

# Enable PATH_INFO so the server can produce URLs of the
# form: http://git.hokietux.net/project.git/xxx/xxx
$feature{'pathinfo'}{'default'} = [1];

# Enable blame, pickaxe search, snapshop, search, and grep
$feature{'blame'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'blame'}{'override'} = [1];

$feature{'pickaxe'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'pickaxe'}{'override'} = [1];

$feature{'snapshot'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'snapshot'}{'override'} = [1];

$feature{'search'}{'default'} = [1];

$feature{'grep'}{'default'} = [1];
$feature{'grep'}{'override'} = [1];
```

Example gitweb config in apache:

```
Alias /gitweb/gitweb.css /usr/share/gitweb/gitweb.css
Alias /gitweb/git-logo.png /usr/share/gitweb/git-logo.png
Alias /gitweb/git-favicon.png /usr/share/gitweb/git-favicon.png
ScriptAlias /gitweb /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi
<Directory /usr/share/gitweb>
  Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</Directory>
<Location /gitweb>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #AuthType Basic
    #AuthName "GITOLITE"
    #AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/gitweb.htpasswd
    #Require valid-user
</Location>
# Securing with users example
<Location /gitweb/SomethingToHide.git>
        Require user myusername
</Location>
```

I've switched to gitolite because...

- it is easier to use
- it has more options (security, grouping etc.)

Comment: My apache config is essentially the same (i'm running this on OSX so some paths are different).  The question I'm asking is regarding *cloning* of the repositories over HTTP (not just viewing them in gitweb).  I don't want to have to manually perform the post-update steps I mentioned in my question above.  Since gitosis automatically manages read access for git-daemon and gitweb viewing, I'm wondering if there is a way for it to manage HTTP cloning access in a similar fashion.  Am I missing something obvious?  Is this possible using gitolite?

Comment: post-update is a server side hook - so it will not run on the server side when you clone (git push would run it).

Comment: I updated my question after looking into this last night, should be more clear what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't limit access to cloning from http:// because Apache handles those requests directly. I've developed a solution using git hooks and file permissions.

I have a Redmine/Gitosis/Gitweb server set up in a shared hosting environment in which the Apache user is *not* the gitosis user. By default, Apache does not have access to my repositories, because gitosis creates them with 750 permissions. I have gitosis successfully populating its projects.list for gitweb at /home/xdgit/gitosis/projects.list, which contains the names of all repositories which should be considered publicly accessible. I have modified my gitosis-admin.git/hooks/post-update hook to contain the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
gitosis-run-hook post-update
git-update-server-info

# Find repo root from ENV or current dir
GIT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)
if [ -z "$GIT_DIR" ]; then
    echo >&2 "fatal: post-receive: GIT_DIR not set"
    exit 1
fi

# Process permissions for each repo
for f in $GIT_DIR/../*.git
do
    # Look for the repo name in projects.list
    if grep -q `basename $f` /home/xdgit/gitosis/projects.list
        then chmod o+rx $f
        else chmod o-rx $f
    fi
done
```

Now whenever I push anything to gitosis-admin.git (such as a change to the gitosis.conf to allow public access for a repository) the post-update hook will automatically change the repository's permissions to allow or deny public access, depending on whether the repo's name appears in projects.list. Since dummy clients **require** the actual repositories to be accessible by Apache directly, this permission-based access control is the ideal solution - not even Apache can access repositories which are not public.

I also developed a mod_rewrite/mod_setenvif solution that detected the presence of the git-daemon-export-ok file in the repository, allowing access if appropriate. It worked, but extra precautions would be needed to explicitly *disallow access* to non-public repos if they are readable by Apache (which they must be). It turned out to be a huge headache and in my case (since file permissions would have to be changed anyway) it was extreme overkill. Hope this helps.